It's possible to connect the cygwin sshd service and switch to the powershell shell
I have a special scenario, I locally use windows 11 comes with openssh client, the server side is a windows server2012 server with cygwin installed, I installed sshd service in cygwin, I locally connect to the server through ssh command, at this time the connection is successful to enter the default bash terminal of cygwin, but when I want to switch to powershell terminal, no matter how I type the command, there is no response.
ssh user@host
powershell
ls
ls

It's looks like that

I also tried direct use the powershell directly
ssh user@host powershell

It looks like this

can there any way to switch to the powershell shell
